# on the purchase of a product from a distributor (price entered by the customer), minimum number of pieces to be refunded (python)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an exercise where I need to know how much the distributor will give back to the customer who bought a product. (constraint: the refund has to be done just with 50 cents, 1€(100 cents) and 2€(200 cents) coins

I can do the calculation to find out how much the distributor should refund.
But the problem I encounter is to try to display the number of coins that make up the total refunded to the customer

Here is what I have done so far :

```
coins = {200: 5, 100: 3, 50: 2, 20: 4, 10: 10, 5: 20, 2: 100, 1: 100}

# Dictionnaire des quantités de chaque valeur de pièce rendue
change_given = {200: 0, 100: 1, 50: 0, 20: 0, 10: 0, 5: 0, 2: 0, 1: 0}

def min_num_coins(amount, change_given):
  # Initialiser le compteur de pièces à zéro
  num_coins = 0
  # Pour chaque valeur de pièce, tant que la somme est supérieure à la valeur de la pièce
  for value in sorted(coins, reverse=True):
      while amount >= value and coins[value] > 0:
      # Incrémenter le compteur de pièces
        num_coins += 1
      # Soustraire la valeur de la pièce de la somme
        amount -= value
      # Décrémenter la quantité disponible de cette valeur de pièce
        coins[value] -= 1
      # Incrémenter la quantité de cette valeur de pièce rendue
        change_given[value] += 1
  # Retourner le nombre de pièces et les pièces rendues
  return num_coins, change_given


# Demander au client de saisir le montant du produit
amount_owed = int(input("Entrez le montant du produit (en euros): "))
# Demander au client de saisir le montant payé
amount_given = int(input("Entrez le montant payé (en euros): "))

# Calculer la somme due
change_due = amount_given - amount_owed

# Séparer la somme due en euros et centimes
euros, centimes = divmod(change_due, 100)

# Appeler la fonction pour obtenir le nombre minimum de pièces
num_coins, coins_given = min_num_coins(centimes, change_given)

# Afficher le résultat
print(f"Il faut rendre {centimes} € et {euros} centimes en {num_coins} pièce(s)")

# Générer un message qui affiche les pièces rendues au client
change_message = "Pièces rendues: "
for value, quantity in coins_given.items():
  if quantity > 0:
    change_message += f"{quantity} x {value // 100} €, "
change_message = change_message[:-2]

# Afficher le message
print(change_message)
```

The error I get when I want to get the number of coins (the example is: the product costs 5€, the customer gives 10€, the distributor gives back 5€ but says he gives 5€ in one coin).

Here is the message I get:
20 € and 0 cents must be returned in 1 coin(s)
Coins returned: 1 x €1, 1 x €0.

Comment: Due to "divmod" the full Euros of the change are stored in "euros" and not processed further (only printed).

Comment: Indeed, you should pass `changed_due` instead of  `centimes` to the coin counting function. Oh, and why is there already a 1 euro coin in the `change_given` dict ?